# overwrite JSON data on server

Tags: objective-c, json, post, nsurlsession

My app is pulling down a JSON file from my server (GoDaddy) and parsing it into an array. The user is then able to add a new record to the existing JSON. I'm running into issues when I try to post all of the data back to server.

To be clear, I'm trying to overwrite the existing file that's on the server with the new data. I know FTP isn't the direction I need to be going, but I'm not using a database of any kind. Just files on the server.

I've made sure the JSON is valid and I've called GoDaddy to make sure I don't need to change any permissions. I've used this directory for FTP before.

Could it be that my `REMOTE_PATH_TO_ROOT_APP_FOLDER` uses FTP credentials? If so, what URL do I need to use?

```
- (void)postExamplesDictionaryToServer:(nonnull NSString *)dName
                                       :(nonnull NSString *)rName
                                       :(nonnull NSData *)jsonData
{
    NSString *userFileURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@TESTER.json", REMOTE_PATH_TO_ROOT_APP_FOLDER, dName, rName];
    NSURL    *userFileURL       = [NSURL URLWithString:userFileURLString];

    NSString *postLength        = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[jsonData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:userFileURL];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

    [[self.session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:jsonData completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
    {
        NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }] resume];
}
```

---

EDIT: I logged the NSERROR passed to the completion handler and got this:

```
Error: (null)
```

BUT...If I change the URL to a file that doesn't already exist on the server, I get this:

```
Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1008 "resource unavailable" 
    UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fca8ad44280 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1008 "(null)"}, 
    NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=ftp://*****:*****@ftp.*****.com/public_html/app/******/File.json, 
    NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=ftp://*****:*****@ftp.*****.com/public_html/app/******/File.json, NSLocalizedDescription=resource unavailable}
```

Does this mean it's not attempting to do an upload task, only a request somehow?

Comment: Are you sure there's no error?  Have you logged the NSError passed to the completion handler?

Comment: I edited to add more information